# Can't load json data in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I am trying to get json data from twitter . http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json
this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("button").click(function(){
                $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json",function(result){
                    $.each(result, function(i, field){
                        $("div").append(field + " ");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

it is from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson
but it is not working !

Comment: Another issue for http://w3fools.com/

Comment: W3schools code example is wrong!? Shocker! Looks like the URL for twitter is returning a 404.

Comment: The URL you are requesting returns error, I think you should add some parameter to it. Try this one and if it works change the parameters. https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running in the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) in JavaScript. This basically says, that you can't access resources from different domains (in your case the other domain would be twitter.com).

One solution is to use JSONP. The twitter [API supports this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). You can run a JSONP-request with jQuery in your case like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json",
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function( result ){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
                        $("div").append(field + " ");
                    });
  }
});
```

<sup>Besides, w3schools is no reliable source for information. Better use something like the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Check out the json document you are trying to load. It returns the following error when I try to access it:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

I would try replacing the url with a working api call to twitter before you worry about whether the code snippet is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to get a document from a different domain and the requested URL is blocking your request due to `Cross-Origin` Resource Sharing. You can read up on that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

You can use JSONP with jQuery which should allow you to complete the request but that page you are requesting gets a 404 error so there's probably not much you can do with the result anyway.

Comment: I changed the URL to  https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi 
and I got to the screen [object Object] [object Object].....

Answer (score 0):

You can Access json data from other domain using $.ajax() jquery method .See the code example below

```
   $.ajax({

   url : " // twitter api url",
   dataType : "JSON",
   cache : false,
   success : function(success)
    {
     $.each(success, function(index,value) {$("div").append(value + ""); })
    }

   error : function() { //Statements for handling ajax errors }

   });
```

The url you are using in that ajax request is returning a json array which contains an error

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please       
migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

You need to migrate to API v1.1 before process the request , Replace the twitter api url with the new json url which is provided in API v1.1